# How to get value of input when autocompleted by Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a simple input for which Google Chrome autocompletion feature kicks in.

When I accept the suggestion with <kbd>→</kbd> and then immediately click a button (without hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>), then accessing `value` of the DOM element returns only the characters I entered by hand, not the whole content of the field. The same occurs with jQuery, i.e. calling `$(input).val()`.

Here is a [minimal example](http://jsfiddle.net/LDC69/) that demonstrates this behavior. I've used `type="email"` input here instead of `type="text"` to ensure that the browser  enables autocompletion, but it behaves exactly the same.

[image: illustration of how I use autocompletion]

The same happens when you click the field after the suggestion is added to your input (higlighted), instead of using <kbd>→</kbd>.

Similar problem occurs on Safari 7, althought there is no problem with retrieving the value, only no event is emitted in the second scenario I described (clicking the field after suggestion is added).

Do anybody has some idea how to circumvent this, apart of disabling autocompletion (which I did)?

---

UPDATE: I've opened [bug with Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=391294). No response till now.

Comment: You want to get value on Clicking OK button?

Comment: It is working on my Google Chrome. I typed the first letter and the suggestions with arrow down + enter and then clicked the button

Comment: @PratikJoshi yes, obtaining the value on click will be sufficient

Comment: @Aleksandrus my question is what to do if user does not press Enter

Comment: @ArturNowak , then do nothing

Comment: You mean the textbox only should consider the values from Auto complete fields?

Comment: fiddle is perfect what is problem?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Type first letter, hover over suggestion - it will fill email. Then click ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=391294) in Chrome, which was corrected as of version 43.0.2357.65 (it is still present in 43.0.2357.45 though).

---

Update as of June 2017: this problem was fixed in Chrome 43 and is no longer present for two years now.

Comment: Have you fixed this problem?

Comment: @DiegoRios I've edited my answer to reflect the current status.

Comment: Got the exact same problem in dec 2018 with Chrome version 71.0.3578.98

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the input field in a form.
This way the input field doesn't autofill. And forces you to click one of the suggestions.

```
<form>
    <input id="email" type="email"/>
</form>
<button>OK</button>
<span></span>
```

Comment: The problem I have with this is that on my Chrome (ver. 36), clicking OK 'deletes' the suggestion. In my particular use case, clicking the button will hide the input, so from the the user standpoint, the value still will be 'invalid'.

Answer (score -1):

On the click of the button, before getting the value, try focusing on the field:

```
document.getElementById("textbox").focus();
var texthere = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

Try that, I believe it will give you the entire value when you click the button.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, even after adding `setTimeout(..., 0)`: http://jsfiddle.net/w6mZu/